# TypeScript Custom Error - Cannot set read only property 'name' of object X

Tags: typescript, class, error-handling

I'm currently creating a custom `Error` class for my NPM package based off of [this tutorial](https://javascript.info/custom-errors). I had this snippet of code:

```
class BlockError extends Error {
  __proto__ = Error
  message: string;

  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.name = "BlockError";
  }
}

function test() {
  throw new BlockError("Whoops!");
}

try {
  test();
} catch(e) {
  console.error(`${e.name}: ${e.message}\n${e.stack}`);
}
```

But this threw `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set read only property 'name' of object 'Whoops!'.` Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! After looking through multiple websites, I went back to the Medium article that gave me the `__proto__ = Error` line. I reasoned, after having never seen it before, that this line which "[had] to be added in TypeScript" for some reason, did not actually need to be there. So, I removed that line, and it started working again. I am not entirely suer of the purpose of that line.